# Angular 6 - Default Dropdown First Option

Tags: angular

I have seen multiple different type answers to this but trying to see best way here some are not working.  I have the following angular 6 select with ngFor it has two fieldGroup values.  I simply want to select the first option.  Thanks for any info.

```
  <select
    class="filter-select"
    [(ngModel)]="customer.fieldGroups"
  >
    <option *ngFor="let fieldGroup of fieldGroups">
      {{ fieldGroup }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select first option by simply setting the value of first option to your ngModel.

```
customer.fieldGroups = value_of_first_option
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vrh5t3)**

Comment: where would the value be set in my example.  The first as isFirst so my first option is 'Customer A' do I just make it that?

Comment: yes, you can also try customer.fieldGroups = fieldGroups[0]

Comment: I added this to the ngInit and it did not work.  I added it to another selection on change method in my typescript and it set.  In the TS file I have:
public fieldGroups = ["Customer A", "Customer B"];

Then I had placed in the ngInit:
customer.fieldGroups = "Customer A";

Comment: @beantownace Added a stackblitz demo for you, you will have to compare your code with the one in stackblitz and find the errors.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<select class="filter-select" [(ngModel)]="customer.fieldGroups">
  <option *ngFor="let fieldGroup of fieldGroups; first as isFirst" [selected]="isFirst">
    {{ fieldGroup }}
  </option>
</select>
```